# Maximum IPC message size exceeded

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

Currently, I'm developing the tool running on a web browser.

In this project, I am using IndexedDB with Dexie.js ver 2.x.

On Google Chrome, I mentioned the error "Maximum IPC message size exceeded". Probably, it's caused by putting so huge data into IndexedDB.
My ad-hoc implementation was that to convert arrays to string by `JSON.stringify`, and I once could achieve the problem. However, the problem happened again.

- In my application an aggregation called `Project` is defined.
- Each `Project` has up to 500 `Input text`.
- Each `Input text` has 1 string and its length is up to 50k.
- Also, each `Project` has `Analysis`, but it contains only analysis parameters.
- Each `Analysis` has a lot of `Result`.
- Each `Result` contains which length is 20k.
- `Input text` and `Result` are gotten by `getAll()` methods of IndexedDB, filtered by `projectId` or `analysisId`.

My question is that ...

1. How to avoid this error?
2. I'd like to rescue the data stored at IndexedDB. I know where the data are stored in a local file system. If possible to do so, how to do it?

Comment: Are you calling IDBObjectStore.prototype.getAll or IDBIndex.prototype.getAll anywhere in your code? How "large" are your objects? Can you please show the tiny portion of the code where you execute the getAll request?

Comment: @Josh I've updated a description. If it's not enough, could you let me know again?

Comment: https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2305003

It looks like they have removed the hard limit from Chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at what causes this error in the Chrome implementation, such as https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/content/browser/indexed_db/indexed_db_database.cc, it occurs when the message size is too large. Here the message size basically refers to the amount of data that is sent from C++ (the browser binary) to Javascript as a result of some processing.

To avoid sending too much data, there are a few things you could do:

- make sure you never call getAll on a lot of data
- use a limit when calling getAll on a potentially large amount of data
- use openCursor instead of getAll
- store smaller objects

I think your best bet is to try switching to openCursor. This will retrieve your items one at a time (per request). This way you will avoid ever running into this error. You lose a tiny bit of speed using a cursor, but you gain scalability.

To get using a cursor to work just like getAll does, it is simple. All you need to do is first declare an empty array, then start the cursor, and iterate, each time adding the cursor item to the array. At the end of iteration you have essentially assembled from one at a time pieces the same array result as from calling getAll.

Comment: Got this error using pouchdb when having a too large sync batch_size. Lowering it solved the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a cursor-like way of querying with Dexie (maybe didn't look hard enough) but I wanted to keep using Dexie as my layer of abstraction.

I was needing to both retrieve all records and retrieve a subset based on ID (same as you) and I came up with the following, which solved our problem:

```js
/**
 * Retrieve all of Dexie collection
 *
 * We can't just call Collection.toArray() because once the result is large
 * enough, we'll get "Maximum IPC message size exceeded" error. This is a
 * memory-friendly implementation. Although maybe a bit slow due to a page
 * size of one.
 */
function retrieveDexieCollection(collection) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const result = []
      await collection.each(r => {
        result.push(r)
      })
      return resolve(result)
    } catch (err) {
      return reject(err)
    }
  })
}

// then later, use our function
const projectIds = [1,2,3]
const records = await retrieveDexieCollection(db
  .whateverYourTableIsCalled
  .where('projectId')
  .anyOf(projectIds))
```

If you need to process the records as you go (I did) you can add a `mappingFunction` parameter and call that for each element before adding it to the array.

The function is pretty flexible because you can pass it any Dexie collection; a whole table or the result of any arbitary query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Dexie's `toArray()` method in some large dataset, try to limit the number of records with `offset(number)` and `limit(number)` , to get the data in batches